# excel rows,find if include,low and high

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

it seems that i cant post my picture.here is my link to it:

picture: http://s18.postimg.org/nfv997rvd/head.png

Hello Stackoverflow.

I have some things I wondering about here. I'll try to take it step by step:

It is marked in orange color:

As mentioned in the example in the picture it says "headphones". I would like it to search through all the lines in column A, to find something that has that name in it, then it should count the number of people, and come out with the number (in how many)
the "middle price" I want it to take the price of B (depending on where it found it called headphones) and take the average price of it.

In secured, as I would like it to count how many of them (from the number, or from the beginning) that have "secured" as "no" and "yes."

would like to use this on several things.

pink:
where would I find the average price of all the goods, and what the name of the particular item is.
same with the highest and lowest price.

How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to try http://superuser.com/ instead of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

to find out how many **Headphones**:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*Headphones*")
```

Note the `*`'s around the word so it can be found anywhere in the text to make a match.

For middle price there are 2 options, depending on how you want to define the average.
If it's a straight average:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,"*Headphones*",B:B)
```

If you want the median, then you will have a slightly more complex formula with

```
=MEDIAN(IF(A1:A100="*Headphones",B1:B100))
```

and entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
maximums and minimums can also be found with the same type of array formula

```
=MAX(IF(A1:A100="*Headphones",B1:B100))
=MIN(IF(A1:A100="*Headphones",B1:B100))
```

Excel also has `COUNTIFS` for multiple criteria:
Secure/Not Secure Headphones:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*Headphones*",E:E,"Ja")
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*Headphones*",E:E,"Nei")
```